# Installing Collabora in Nextcloud with docker

Tags: php, path, nextcloud

I have installed Collabora in NextCloud. I use the container collabora/code for that purpose. And when I try to access to the collabora inside nextcloud, it only shows the title.

When I check the logs, there is a line that says the following:

```
93.59.45.238 - - [27/Dec/2017:20:52:53 +0000] “GET /lool/https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.mydomain.foo%2Findex.php%2Fapps%2Frichdocuments%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2F42_ociq0wuinnaa%3Faccess_token%3DlfVzC4H6skhX4pHGt95NtF62qkSNyXwT%26access_token_ttl%3D0%26permission%3Dedit/ws?WOPISrc=https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.mydomain.foo%2Findex.php%2Fapps%2Frichdocuments%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2F42_ociq0wuinnaa&compat=/ws HTTP/1.1” 400 0 “-” “Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0” “-”
```

So, there is a 400 error in `/lool/ path`. Does anybody have the same problem? Do you need more information? Thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: 400 error usually means that it was a malformed request. What do the collabora logs say?